# How to update the label of p:selectCheckboxMenu without the component being closed after ajax call in primefaces?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

There is one problem occurring when I am trying to dynamically generate the label from the backing bean. The problem is that the dropdown that appears vanishes for each selection but the label is updated properly. Is there a workaround for this?

```xml
<p:selectCheckboxMenu value="#{formBean.selectedMovies}" label="#{formBean.moviesLabel}"    id="Movies" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{formBean.movies}" ></f:selectItems>
    <p:ajax update="Movies" listener="#{formBean.populateLabel}"></p:ajax>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

and

```
//Backing bean 
public void populateLabel() {
    /* Populating the label with the selected options */
    moviesLabel = new String("");
    if (selectedMovies.size() == 0) {
        moviesLabel = "Select";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedMovies.size(); i++) {
            if (moviesLabel.length() == 0) {
                moviesLabel = selectedMovies.get(i);
            } else {
                moviesLabel = moviesLabel + "," + selectedMovies.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you working with the latest nightly build ? http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3627   if you aren't, then try... http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/3.3-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Hi ... thanks for the reply ... I added the build to my project ... i tried giving it an event and trying to do the same but i still have the same problem ... Also i would like to know if the new build has anyother evnet like "onmenuclose" apart from the change event ???

Comment: I would like to tell you that the previous method does work but the problem is that every time a selection is made the menu closes and then i would have open the menu again to make any other selection.

Comment: You mean that adding an up to date jar solved the original problem?

Comment: @Daniel: Hi, no i meant that the problem still persists even after adding the upto date jar . I want to know if apart from the "change" event are there any other events like "onmenuclose" associated with the pre-built <p:ajax> event. If there is then my problem will be solved . I went through the documentation and searched on google but there is stunning lack of any information on the events associated with them .

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is how

add `widgetVar="someVarName"` to your `p:selectCheckboxMenu`

and modify your `p:"ajax` by adding `oncomplete="someVarName.show()"`

complete  code :

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu widgetVar="someVarName" value="#{usersManagmentPage.selectedMovies}" 
        label="#{usersManagmentPage.moviesLabel}"   id="Movies" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{usersManagmentPage.movies}" ></f:selectItems>
    <p:ajax oncomplete="someVarName.show()" listener="#{usersManagmentPage.populateLabel}" update="Movies" ></p:ajax>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

---

**In latest PrimeFaces** you should use `oncomplete="PF('someVarName').show()"` instead of `oncomplete="someVarName.show()"`

Comment: In case someone is also wondering: By now you have to use oncomplete="PF('someVarName').show()" to make it work - Took me a while to figure out

Comment: Sort of works, but with this solution, when the menu is opened again by show(), it is always re-positionend at the top of the menu item list, which can be a PITA when you have meny entries.
Any ideas on how to work around this behavior?

Comment: Also deselecting an item does not work in my case. It gets immediately reselected.

Comment: this is work but widget position is different location point on page. I have datatable and its each of cell include selectCheckboxMenu

Comment: Selecting All values does not call a listener...