# Carry over state from PrimeFaces onstart to oncomplete using JS / jQuery only

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I'm using a `<p:selectCheckboxMenu multiple="true">`

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="options"
                      widgetVar="optionsCheckboxMenu"
                      value="#{someBean.selectedStrings}"
                      valueChangeListener="#{someBean.onSelectedOptionsChange}"
                      multiple="true">
    <f:selectItems id="items"
                   value="#{someBean.selectableStrings}" />
    <p:ajax process="@this"
            update="@this"
            onstart="var panelShown = $('#options_panel').css('display') == 'block';"
            oncomplete="console.log('PANEL SHOWN: ' + panelShown);
                        if (panelShown) { PF('optionsCheckboxMenu').show(); }" />
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

The component uses a `valueChangeListener="#{someBean.onSelectedOptionsChange}"` which adjusts the selected items so they are valid, so I must use `<p:ajax process="@this" update="@this" ...>` in some way.

However, using `update="@this"` also has the effect of the component closing its related check box overlay panel. This can be remedied by calling `PF('optionsCheckboxMenu').show();` in the oncomplete callback (see [How to update the label of p:selectCheckboxMenu without the component being closed after ajax call in primefaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964759/how-to-update-the-label-of-pselectcheckboxmenu-without-the-component-being-clos)).

The component however also lets you remove items via the X's in the input (when no panel is being displayed). The `PF('optionsCheckboxMenu').show();` will display the overlay at all times.

What I want now is, to detect, before the AJAX request is sent, which state the overlay panel has currently, so that I only re-show the overlay panel if it was previously shown as well.

What I tried was to create a JavaScript var called `panelShown` in the `onstart` callback to evaluate that later in the `oncomplete`. However, when executing the `oncomplete`, the var `panelShown` is undefined.

**QUESTION**:

How do you carry over state (a simple JS var) from the PrimeFaces `onstart` to the `oncomplete` callback without having to go via some bean/remote command?

It occurrs to me that this should easily be possible, but I might be missing sth. right now.

PS: my form uses `prependId="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `p:ajax onstart="..."` and `oncomplete="..."` values are rendered in two separate JavaScript functions. Variables defined within a function are only available to that function. So you need to store your property globally somehow. A way to do that is using `window`, like:

```js
window.panelShown = ...
```

in your `onstart` and access it in `oncomplete` like:

```js
if (window.panelShown) { ... }
```

See also:

- [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)
- [Define a global variable in a JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-a-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

If you want to to get rid of hardcoded variable names, you might be interested in knowing that you can access the current component in Expression Language using `#{component.clientId}`. You can use this in combination with the PrimeFaces EL functions `p:escapeJavaScriptVarName` and `p:resolveWidgetVar` and the JavaScript API function `PrimeFaces.escapeClientId` to get something generic like:

```html
<p:ajax process="@this"
        update="@this"
        onstart="window.#{p:escapeJavaScriptVarName(component.clientId)}Shown=$(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{component.clientId}')+'_panel').css('display')=='block';"
        oncomplete="if(window.#{p:escapeJavaScriptVarName(component.clientId)}Shown){PF('#{p:resolveWidgetVar('@this', component)}').show()}" />
```

See also:

- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/elFunctions
- https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/javascriptAPI